# Encoding issue when writing Hebrew to text file, with Python

Tags: python, file, encoding, utf-8, io

Django Project

Encoding problem:
The flow of code

1. reading Excel file
2. manipulate the data from  the Excel
3. create new txt file and write into it
4. send the txt file to the client

   ```
   coding = "utf8"
   file = open(filename, "w", encoding=coding, errors="ignore") 

   for row in excel_data_df.iloc():
       line = manipulate(row)
       file.write(line)
   file.close()
   file_data = open(filename, "r", encoding=coding, errors="ignore")
   response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename
   ```

every thing is working just fine but when I open the the file with **ANSI Encoding** all the Hebrew change into gibberish

I have try to change the coding with every Hebrew option https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

The Hebrew coding should be write with ASCII NEW CODE or ASCII WINDOWS TEXT,
any ideas?

Comment: Open the file in the encoding it was written in.  "ANSI" is a Windows term for "the default encoding for a locale-specific version of Windows" and varies by internationalized version of Windows.  Anything but the encoding the file was written in will be gibberish.  If you don't know the original encoding, tools like [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) can guess, but can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the mode to "rb" and remove the encoding parameter

```
file = open(filename, "w") 

for row in excel_data_df.iloc():
    line = manipulate(row)
    file.write(line)
file.close()
file_data = open(filename, "rb")
response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/vnd.ms- 
excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename
```